# "Tables sizes" - why is it wrong?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

For example, "Tables sizes" as far as I know, is wrong. Correct is "Table sizes". But it may mean either "sizes of the one table" or "sizes of many tables". How to specify that I want to say about many tables?

What rule is used there? Where can I read more about it?

Comment: Can you give a full sentence for context (where the meaning of 'Table(s) sizes' is relevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways in English grammar to indicate possession.

1. One is called "the Saxon genitive" (to indicate its origin as a Germanic noun case), and appears as an "apostrophe S" in writing. Technically, this morpheme is the inflectional suffix `{-Z₂}`, with three allomorphs /-s/, /-z/, and /-əz/, identical in form with the noun plural suffix `{-Z₁}` and with the 3rd person singular present tense verb suffix `{-Z₃}`.

> (Parenthetically, it's always seemed odd to me that, of the [only 8 or 9 inflectional suffixes left in English](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Inflection.pdf), ***three*** are identical. I suspect this is just a symptom of inflectional death)

2. The other way of expressing possession in English grammar is called "the Romance genitive" (to indicate its origin as the Latin preposition *de*, with various compounds), and it uses the English equivalent of *de*, namely a prepositional phrase with *of*.

Either one can be used, in most cases, but there is a strong tendency to use (1) with human possessors and (2) with non-human possessors, e.g:

- *Bill's/the man's/Fido's leg*
- *the leg of the table/the trip/the argument*

Note that most metaphoric uses of possession use *of*; abstract and formal sentences are apt to contain more Romance-derived words as well as a Romance genitive. Generally speaking, Germanic influences in English are shorter, earthier, and more common than Romance influences in English; this is not limited to grammar and vocabulary.

So, getting to the question, why **is** *tables sizes* wrong? First, we're talking about tables here, not people, so we wouldn't use a Saxon genitive. Thus

- *sizes of tables*

works fine. And that's the answer to your question about how you specify that more than one table was sized.

But putting *tables* in front of *sizes* complicates things even more.
Unlike the situation in Romance languages, an English modifier **must not** agree with a plural noun it modifies. Even though no one buys only one shoe at a *shoe store*, it's still not a **shoes store*.

This rule applies with any one-word modifier that goes before the noun; it's part of what's sometimes called "the eleven-year-old boy rule" because of the opposition

- *an eleven-year-old boy ~ a boy eleven years old*

This example shows how hyphens are used to make the phrase *eleven years old* into a single word, so that it can precede the noun, and also how the plural marker is removed because preposed modifiers can't be plural.